# Responsive tables

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, responsive

I am trying to get the table data I'm working on responsive in a way which I don't think is possible as far as I know, unless other people here think it is?

Basically I have a table which at max size shows 3 TD elements within a TR. When scrolling down to min size the TR only displays 2 TD elements anymore, where the previously third TD is displayed under the 2. Something like this (more or less visual representation):

Max-width:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>First table data</td>  <td>Second table data</td>   <td>Third table data</td> 
            <td>Fourth table data</td> <td>Fifth table data</td>   <td>Sixth table data</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Min-width:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>First table data</td>  <td>Second table data</td> 
            <td>Third table data</td>  <td>Fourth table data</td> 
            <td>Fifth table data</td>   <td>Sixth table data</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

is this even possible? If so, how to start? Would this require jQuery?

Comment: What is "table data"? Pure text? *** You can achieve this functionality with CSS floating (instead of a table).

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks - Then set the width so they wrap in 3's. 33%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Set the `TD` elements to float left and set `min-width`

http://jsfiddle.net/RnmLF/1/

Just change the size of the container to see it working.

I would look into whether or not you need to use a table though. Tables are only used for displaying tabular data these days (we are not in the 90's any more)

**EDIT**

I took the liberty to provide a NON table version for accessibility (see @timmied for the reasons why)

http://jsfiddle.net/nW2hx/

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Need to use tables for this, it's how the data is inserted from the CMS. 

Solution seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Kvkbe/6/embedded/result/

Made a small change to fill the width when resizing to 2 TD's to 50% min-width.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, if all your data cells are in one row. (See @webnoob his solution )If not, you might also want to put your data in DIV elements. They can do this easily.

You have no row or column header so I assume you can easily do this, because your data obviously have no relation to it's current column or row.

As said in my comment below, the reason why I mention using something else then table is because it seems not to represent tabular data. Read more here : [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Comment: No problem, a really good solution. But it seems OP does not want to represent actual tabular data. For multiple reason (for example accessibility) OP should take another look at his html. A good read on it can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: I have edited my example to provide a non table approach to help the war on accessibility :)

Comment: Hi timmied, would also have gone for another solution then tables but with how the CMS populates the data this is the only possible way for the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Please check your query at below link, here you can solve your problem of Responsive table

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Comment: Thanks, found this link too while researching, but not really the solution I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using divs instead of table/tr/td, here is one extensive example different options using flexbox: [Really Responsive tables using Flexbox](https://hashnode.com/post/really-responsive-tables-using-css3-flexbox-cijzbxd8n00pwvm53sl4l42cx). At the most complex level, what you will get is as follows:

```
First Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth Seventh Eighth

First  Third  Fifth Seventh
Second Fourth Sixth Eighth

First   Fifth
Second  Sixth
Third   Seventh
Fourth  Eighth
```