# Collapse table columns into rows

Tags: html, css

How to collapse html table columns into rows?
Lets say i have a html table like this

```
Hello|World
One|Two|Three
```

and i want all columns to collapsed into row for responsive. Can it be done with CSS?

```
Hello
World
One
Two
Three
```

Comment: what code do you have? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Basically the fiddle from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13861083/1326147) does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/RnmLF/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change from float to display block in your media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
td { 
    float:none; 
    display:block; 
} 
}
```

Obviously, change your `max-width` to whatever you like.

You are basically telling you `CSS` that when the page is being displayed at a certain resolution, in this case `400px`, then change the attributes from `td` to `float:none`, and `display:block;`

Hope this helps :)